# asp.net with c# dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.addemployee_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'DropDownState_SelectedIndexChanged' and no
>   extension method 'DropDownState_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ASP.addemployee_aspx' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. How do you want us to help you if we can't see your code?

Comment: Post your C# code behind file. and check whether you have `DropDownState_SelectedIndexChanged` event or not?